# Vectors in align environment with additional split

Tags: numbering, align, matrices

I want to do the following: Some vectors (using `pmatrix`) aligned in an `align` environment but with a single equation number (using `split`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
{\bf a}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
\, ,
&{\bf b}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \\ -\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}} \\ \tfrac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\, , \\
{\bf c}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\tfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} \\ 0 \\ -\tfrac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\, ,
&{\bf d}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \\ \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}} \\ \tfrac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\, .
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I get error message like Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
     }$\hfill \endtemplate. Using `eqnarray` it works. Why is that and is it possible to use align instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want only one equation number, so think of this as a single equation,
and use the substructure `aligned` inside of that:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
{\bf a}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
\, ,
&{\bf b}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \\ -\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}} \\ \tfrac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\, , \\
{\bf c}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\tfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} \\ 0 \\ -\tfrac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\, ,
&{\bf d}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{3} \\ \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}} \\ \tfrac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\, .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

`split` can support only a single `&`, so any attempt to have additional
alignment points will result in the `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.` that you encountered.

there are several different sub-structures provided by `amsmath`.  take a look at the documentation: `texdoc amsmath`.  (and `mathtools` provides another that's "missing" from `amsmath`.)